# match string that is a domain/url with optional port eg: www.ex-ample.com:32000

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I am trying to match something to the effect of

`www.ex-ample.com:32000`

where the `:32000` portion is optional

So far the best I can come up with is something that will match the entirety but not with one group acting optionally. What am I failing to see/add in the pattern?

```
^([a-z0-9-.]+)?(:\d{1,5})$
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.. improper placement of the question mark..

```
^([a-z0-9-.]+)([:\d]{1,5})?$
```

putting it there got exactly the result I wanted.